# Easiest way to overwrite a series of files with zeros

Tags: file, overwrite

I'm on Linux. I have a list of files and I'd like to overwrite them with zeros and remove them. I tried using

```
srm file1 file2 file3 ...
```

but it's too slow (I have to overwrite and remove ~50 GB of data) and I don't need that kind of security (I know that srm does a lot of passes instead of a single pass with zeros).

I know I could overwrite every single file using the command

```
cat /dev/zero > file1
```

and then remove it with rm, but I can't do that manually for every single file.

Is there a command like srm that does a single pass of zeros, or maybe a script that can do `cat /dev/zero` on a list of files instead of on a single one? Thank you.

Comment: You should check xargs ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, using `stat` to get the correct size to write, and `dd` to overwrite the file, might be what you need:

```
for f in $(<list_of_files.txt)
do
  read blocks blocksize < <(stat -c "%b %B" ${f})
  dd if=/dev/zero bs=${blocksize} count=${blocks} of=${f} conv=notrunc
  rm ${f}
done
```

Use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/zero` for (slightly) better erasure semantics.

Edit: added `conv=notrunc` option to `dd` invocation to avoid truncating the file when it's opened for writing, which would cause the associated storage to be released before it's overwritten.

Comment: I doubt that this works because `of` in `dd` will be simply open for writing, not updating.

Comment: @lhf Good call... that will truncate the file, releasing the storage before overwriting. I'll add the correct option to avoid that...

Answer (score 8):

I use `shred` for doing this.

The following are the options that I generally use.

1. `shred -n 3 -z <filename>` - This will make 3 passes to overwrite the file with random data. It will then make a final pass overwriting the file with zeros. The file will remain on disk though, but it'll all the `0`'s on disk.
2. `shred -n 3 -z -u <filename>` - Similar to above, but also unlinks (i.e. deletes) the file. The default option for deleting is `wipesync`, which is the most secure but also the slowest. *Check the man pages for more options.*

***Note:*** *`-n` is used here to control the number of iterations for overwriting with random data. Increasing this number, will result in the `shred` operation taking longer to complete and better shredding. I think 3 is enough but maybe wrong.*

Comment: The default iteration for shred is 3, so it will be the same without `-n 3`

Comment: Yes @Monica, you're correct. But I'm a fan of explicit instead of implicit in all things code.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `srm` is to destroy the data in the file before releasing its blocks.

`cat /dev/null > file` is not at all equivalent to `srm` because 
it does not destroy the data in the file: the blocks will be released with the original data intact.

Using `/dev/zero` instead of `/dev/null` does not even work because `/dev/zero` never ends.

Redirecting the output of a program to the file will never work for the same reason given for `cat /dev/null`.

You need a special-purpose program that opens the given file for writing, writes zeros over all bytes of the file, and then removes the file. That's what `srm` does.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I meant /dev/zero instead of /dev/null. I have corrected the mistake in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a command like srm that does a single pass of zeros,

Yes. SRM does this with the correct parameters. From man srm:
srm -llz

-l     lessens the security. Only two passes are written: one mode with
0xff and a final mode random values.

-l     -l for a second time lessons the security even  more:  only  one
random pass is written.

-z     wipes the last write with zeros instead of random data
srm -llzr will do the same recursively if wiping a directory.

You can even use 'srm -llz [file1] [file2] [file3] to wipe multiple files i this way with a single command